# A better definition of ‘evolution’?

Tags: evolution

Occasionally on this site I’ve noticed the following definition of evolution being given:

> Evolution is a change of allele frequency through time in a population

( [For example, from here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/53374))

Recently the following ([From here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/55790)):

> The statement "evolution is driven by mutations" is very misleading if not simply wrong. Just have a look at an intro course to evolutionary biology!
>
> In short, evolution is a change of allele frequency over time.

But mutations are important to evolution, and I feel *must* be included in the definition.

**Here’s why that concerns me**:  One group of evolution deniers, and others like them, use comments like these above to try and show a weakness in evolution.
See:
http://creation.com/don-t-fall-for-the-bait-and-switch

With comments like:

> “It is a bit of a trick played by using sloppy language. Evolutionists use adaptation, which is observed, to support evolution, which is an entirely different process. It is an example of bait and switch.”

Also:

> “Next time someone says that evolution is an observed scientific fact make sure you get them to clearly define what they are talking about.
>   They will almost certainly be referring to adaptation but want you to believe they have proved evolution.
>   Don’t be fooled. Sloppy language leads to sloppy thinking.”

Ok, I hate to give them ‘air-time’ by posting that, but perhaps it will cause us to clarify ourselves better.  Answers like "a change of allele frequency through time" just end up feeding right into this kind of evolution-denial.

**SO, here’s my question**  Since there’s a lot people here smarter than me:  Can someone please offer up a stronger definition of evolution than just ‘a change in allele frequency over time’?

In researching answers I found this on Berkeley’s site:

> “Biological evolution, simply put, is descent with modification. This definition encompasses small-scale evolution (changes in gene frequency in a population from one generation to the next) and large-scale evolution (the descent of different species from a common ancestor over many generations).”

I like that it goes beyond small-scale (which these others would just call adaptation).  But this doesn't mention natural selection, and mutations; which I feel are important distinctions given the kind of comments these deniers make. Is there a reason Berkeley's definition didn't include those distinctions?

---

EDIT:  Can someone explain the down-vote?  I followed everything outlined under [How to ask a good question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You might try over at T.O. ... http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/evolution-definition.html

Comment: I agree with the Berkeley statement and your assertation. "Change in allele frequency over time", by itself, is not sufficient.

Comment: But they're the ones using sloppy language.  Evolution IS adaptation which takes place over generations.  The mechanism by which the adaptation happens is mostly change in allele frequency, though other things like mutations, viruses inserting bits of genetic material, or wholesale co-opting of different life forms (e.g. mitochondria) play their parts too.  But we could observe the fact of evolution without knowing anything about the underlying genetic mechanisms.  As Darwin & Wallace actually did.

Comment: @jamesqf:  As I read it (and I have read a lot of their material), creationists fully believe in adaptation, speciation, and natural selection.  In their minds, these mechanisms are built into life’s design.  Animals where created with plenty of built-in variety, seen as adaptation via natural selection.  As rabbit spread the globe, some became desert rabbits, some arctic rabbits.  All done via a ‘change in (PRE-EXISTING) allele frequency over time’.  So when we use that phrase as our definition of evolution, it just confirms to them their own stance.

Comment: (cont).  **The important ‘distinction’ I’m looking for**: is one that includes the creation of new genetic information, which as I understand it to be, is via mutation.

Comment: It is pointless to say that "Creationists believe adaption" without knowing what they mean by it.  It is not at all clear that they are using the term to mean hereditary changes to the DNA. Also, not being tethered by the evidence, some Creationists might mean something very very different from other Creationists.

Comment: And the issue is, of course there is no evidence of all this "pre-existing" variation.  When a bacterial sample evolves resistance, it's due to a DNA change. There was no resistance allele hiding, it didn't exist until the mutation.  Creationists are just wrong about the facts here.

Comment: @RunzWitScissors: Well, the operative phrase there is "creationists fully believe".  It's a religious belief, and no amount of fact or logic is going to change that.  The most you can get them to do is weasel around the idea, with their "adaptation".

Comment: "Change in allele frequency" also encompasses mutations. The occurrence of a new mutation increases the frequency of that variant from 0 to whatever percent of the population the organism that carries it comprises. Similarly, the frequency of all the other variants at that locus decreases by the same percentage.

Comment: @RunzWitScissors the problem is the continued generation of new genetic material is not actually necessary for evolution, so there is absolutely no reason to add it in to the definition. If starting right now no mutations at all occurred ever, life would still continue to evolve for quite a long time.

Comment: @swbarnes:  True, but that doesn't see to deter them.  BTW, your bacterial resistance example quite frankly is one example of what they would call a bait-and-switch.  See [here](https://creation.com/images/pdfs/tj/j8_1/j8_1_5-6.pdf). and [here](http://creation.com/does-the-acquisition-of-antibiotic-and-pesticide-resistance-provide-evidence-for-evolution).

Comment: "Evolutionists"... I'm not sure that I like that term. How about "members of the general public that understand reason". But more seriously, this should go on meta, not the main site. It seems to be more about if we, as a community, should be more careful when defining evolution.

Answer (score 2):

The focus upon definition of term is a [rhetorical strategy often employed to confuse the issue](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/27/Appeal-to-Definition), especially by laity when discussing technical matters. [Word meaning and use](http://williamstarr.net/teaching/speech_acts/Grice-1969-Utterers_Meaning%E2%80%93and_Intentions.pdf) are easily a source of ambiguity, confusion, contradiction and such that the appeal to the dictionary definition is often an appeal to false authority. At the very least it is worth pointing out that aside from etymology and morphology, empirical disputes are not settled by consulting Merriam-Webster.

"Evolution" is a fairly general concept and it can be useful when discussing technicalities to specify "biological evolution".  For example, "water" might mean specifically "H2O" or generally "clear, odorless, tasteless liquid"  or possibly might be used without qualification in distinguishing "potable water" from ocean water, et cetera.

Consider that the definition of term is not so much the pertinent legacy of biological evolution (pace Darwin, Wallace et. alii). The kind of explanation biological evolution uses is it's hallmark. In particular, biological evolution removed teleology (the study of purpose)) from biology.

For example:

A teleological explanation of biology:
1) This plant is photosynthesizing in order to survive.
2) This plants species is surviving.

A biologically evolutionary explanation of species:
1) This plant is photosynthesizing
2) Plant species which photosynthesize have an increased likelihood of survival.

Note that survival is still at play, but the argument is no longer circular. This is not to say that cause has been cited, however, the logical structure of the argument no longer "[begs the question](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/begging-the-question)"

Answer (score 1):

This is the one I use for my intro to biology students.

"Biological evolution is a change in the number of times *specific heritable characteristics*(aka genes) occur within a population over time."

Keep in mind this is a description of the definition{law} of evolution not the theory of evolution. And is just a diffrent way of stating, "Evolution is a change of allele frequency through time in a population"

I use this becasue the possibility of evolution in machines, epigenetics, and xenobiology is discussed and students have a difficult time separating genes and nucleotide sequences, and not every student will know what allele frequency means.

defining evolution with natural selection would be pointless and circular, since natural selection is part of the theory that explains how and why evolution happens (but not the only mechanism by which it operates). We do not define gravity by the proposed mechanism but by the observed behavior of matter.

If mutation stopped tomorrow evolution would continue, It would not end until there was no life left to vary. So using mutation to define evolution would be false.

Deniers will deny no matter how you change the definition, there is no reason to bastardize the science to try to please them. You would be better spending your time discussing things like ring species or asking them to define "kind." Likewise speciation is the outcome and subset of evolution and completely covered in the existing definition. If they have a problem with speciation let them argue with it, speciation is only one form of evolution. If nothing else it will encourage them to learn something about what they argue.

Comment: I’m not sure if that definition is much better.  That definition fits perfectly well with their (creationists) model.  As that article specified, they fully believe in adaptation.  Those ‘_heritable characteristics_’ to them, were there to begin with and don’t ‘arise’ later.

Comment: that means they don't believe in mutation which a whole new problem, and can be dealt with by searching for a paper on mutation.  Try chasing their definition instead of  letting them use a strawman to get you to twist the definition of evolution to suit what they want.

Comment: since the focus seems to be a non-scientific argument this site may help you. http://www.talkorigins.org/

Comment: adaptation and evolution are not really distinct concepts, paleontologists might talk about tetrapods adaptation to life on land which has continued for hundreds of millions of years. Unsurprisingly it sounds like the creationists you talk to don't understand the terminology they are using.

Comment: They do seem to understand their terminology, but just point out that many forms of 'adaptation' don't involve the creation of new genetic information.  That's why I was calling for a better definition that just a change in frequency.

Comment: John: BTW, please explain further your comment that "If mutation stopped tomorrow evolution would continue".  You have me intrigued.

Comment: This is a much more correct definition, especially since it carefully distinguishes evolution as an observable fact from theories of the causes of evolution.

Comment: @RunzWitScissors evolution will continue until there is is absolutely no variation within a population which basically means until the population is extinct or entirely clones. evolution only requires variation in heritable characteristics and it can continue until that variation is exhausted. Normally mutation keeps adding new variation but it takes time for evolution to spread/eliminate mutations. Also it is rarely all or nothing, balances of multiple competing mutations exist (Evolutionarily Successful Strategies) so some variation will also tend to be preserved.

Comment: @RunzWitScissors in line with John's comment consider a population with two virus-resistance alleles. Virus A is common, so resistance allele A spreads in the population, leading to less virus A and more virus B, so now resistance allele B is selected for and spreads through the population, etc. Continual evolution even in the absence of mutation.

Comment: reference for Evolutionarily Stable Strategies (yes I know my error)http://www.nature.com/scitable/knowledge/library/game-theory-evolutionary-stable-strategies-and-the-25953132?utm_source=%CE%B1%CE%B8%CE%B7%CE%9D%CE%95%CE%91+subscribers&utm_campaign=0a22881ee9-01_a8inea_Newsletter12_17_2013&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_903691d971-0a22881ee9-116007725&ct=t(01_a8inea_Newsletter12_17_2013)

Comment: @John & iayork - Certainly variation & adaptation via natural selection can continue without mutations.  Yet in light of the central theme of this post:  to a creationist, those things are simply a part of their creation-model.  The distinction between that and evolution is issue:  The change in existing genetic material to pull from (via mutations).  It's like arguing with someone: 'look, I can shuffle these cards, therefore cards evolved'.  Their response:  'I believe cards can be shuffled as well.  It's the sufficient addition of new well-working cards that are in question'.

Comment: @RunzWitScissors 1. shuffling is a randomizing process, NS is not. 2. then their problem is with mutation, speciation, the fossil record, and the implication of evolution. each of which can be dealt with individually. Including accessory process like mutation in the definition makes it  inaccurate. They are basically saying, "I believe you can walk around the block but I don't believe it is possible for a person to walk across the country." the process is the same they are claiming that it somehow stops running after a certain amount of time. this is a claim THEY must provide evidence for.

Comment: @John  Yes, I get that NS is not random. Card shuffling is an _analogy_ for genetic variation in a population.  Shuffling existing cards is different than shuffling AND creating new cards.  And your 'around the block' 'across the country' analogy isn't accurate.  More like selecting various pre-existing vehicles to travel with, vs. selecting AND creating new vehicles to travel with.

Comment: @RunzWitScissors no both mechanisms are identical the only difference is the size of the population and the run time. New vehicles for the genes are created with each generation, species are just arbitrary but useful groupings inside the one single population that is all life. Once time is considered all populations blur into each other, all life is one giant ring species.

Comment: @RunzWitScissors creationists mistakenly believe species is constant and concrete and not just an artifact how human need to think.  when you show them what species actually are they retreat to their own undefined term "kinds" which the claim (without evidence) does not change.

Answer (score 1):

I think that any definition that is useful for explaining evolution to laymen must contain the concept of natural selection. Here's my version:

*Evolution is a gradual change in organisms over many generations caused by the combination of (1) random variation in genes among individuals and (2) the fact that those individuals that best survive and reproduce will transmit their genes to the next generation.*${}^1$

That random variation arises (in part) from mutations is just a detail, in my mind. The fundamental mechanism, which is *very* hard to deny, is that even though variation in any individual's genes are completely random, the combination of this variation with survival of the fittest will produce a strong tendency to adapt to the environment. If someone has difficulty accepting / understanding this principle, it's easy to setup computer simulations that demonstrate the effect hands-on. In my experience this convinces pretty much everyone.

The "bait and switch" argument on the page you link to is fundamentally flawed because there is no difference between what they call "adaptation" and "evolution". Both are evolutionary processes, resulting from variation and natural selection. It's just that these creationists are willing to accept *some* consequences of evolution, but refuse to accept all of them. This is just a rhetorical device that lets them accuse scientists of "equivocation" (which sounds pretty sophisticated). Also, there are the usual falsehoods: "no intermediate forms", "mutations do not generate new information", and evolution is "just a hypothetical philosophy without observational scientific support".

But then again, creationist do not really care about the scientific arguments --- they only pretend to do so because they know science has credibility. They are driven by belief, and arguing with them is usually pointless.

---

${}^1$ I am aware that this is not the most general definition one could give, as it does not encompass genetic drift and other mechanisms described by modern evolutionary theory. But I think it's an appropriate one for explaining evolution, as in the discussion brought up by the OP.

Comment: I do like that answer.  Thank you.  BTW, please do share at least some of the bigger errors on that page.  An acquaintance gave me that link, and I'd love to point out some of them.

Comment: recombination is not necessary for evolution

Comment: If you really want to understand evolution consider explaining artificial selection first, it is basically the simplified version. these videos are very good approach laying everything out very clearly. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhHOjC4oxh8.

Comment: @John,  I did not mention recombination?

Comment: @RunzWitScissors, I have added some comments on the creationist page. If you want to dig deeper, I would recommend Ken Miller's work, http://www.millerandlevine.com/km/evol/

Comment: This is a bad answer.  Modern evolutionary theory recognizes natural selection as one of the main drivers of evolution, but by no means is it the only one. Ignoring the past 75 years worth of understanding is a very bad start to a definition.

Comment: @Roland.  Good link, will check it out.  Regarding no difference between adaptation and evolution:  one is a subset of the other.  You can have adaptation without any change in existing genetic information.  Finch beak adaptation is one example.  Yes, creationists are willing to accept what you call 'some consequences':  just adaptation.  The entire point of their article is that too often 'adaptation' examples are given as examples of a process that can 'turn molecules into men'.  And the whole point of my post is to create a better definition of evolution than 'change in gene frequency'

Comment: @Roland.  Also, can you provide me some links refuting their case that mutations do not generate new information?  I'd love to pass those along.  (I have searched myself some but would like to find better ones).

Comment: @RunzWitScissors,  I think "information" is poorly defined in this context. But it's rather obvious that mutations can create new sequences, and so it provides a mechanism for exploring new genotypes.

Comment: @iayork,  I wasn't trying to summarize modern evolutionary theory. (And I don't think I'm the right person to do it.) I was shooting for an easy-to-understand definition that conveys the basic idea to the layman. And to be pedagogical, I think variation + natural selection should be the centerpiece.

Comment: If you're going to come up with a definition for a layman, maybe it shouldn't be actively misleading.  Your definition here is actively misleading.

Comment: @Roland My mistake your wording was a bit confusing.

Comment: Remember to define evolution you are looking for the basic observations that the theory was created to explain. That observations is that the variations in a population change over generations. points for mentioning equivocation,

Comment: @iayork  I don't think this is "actively misleading". I understand that "change in the heritable characteristics over generations" or some such is a more general definition that encompasses modern evolutionary theory, but that wasn't the issue here. I think it is necessary to focus on natural selection first if you want to teach evolution. If you wanted to teach physics, you would start with Newton's mechanics, not general relativity; Newton's is not the most up-to-date theory, but that doesn't mean that teaching it is misleading. Basics first. Refinement comes later.

Comment: If you don't actually understand what evolution is, you shouldn't be answering questions about it.

Comment: @Roland focusing on natural selection is counterproductive, a great way to explain evolution is to compare the mechanisms, natural selection, sexual selection, artificial selection, ect. To use your analogy we don't define thermodynamics as only Conservation of Energy.

Comment: @John,  well I agree with that. I very much like how Darwin introduces selection in the origin of species by starting with selective breeding, for example.  But those are all selection mechanisms, and I think they are included in the definition I suggested ("individuals that best survive").

Comment: except survival is secondary to passing on your genes, that is how things like kin selection and such function. may behaviors drastically reduce survival in return for helping spread genes, you could eliminate survival from the definition entirely. .