# Examples of creating a new animal species by humans

Tags: evolution, reproduction, species

So recently, I was arguing with my friend who happens to be creationist. As he does not believe in the "theory of evolution" I asked him how he can explain such a big diversity in the dog Canis familiaris sppecies. (The example taken from *Charles Darwin's on the Origin of Species* saying that humans made to dogs what mother nature has done to every species)

My friend replied something like:

> Well, having chihuahuas or huskies is one thing but, getting a tetrapod from a fish is a something which can never happen.

I realized that indeed the Darwin's example isn't perfect... Even though, due to size chihuahuas and hounds can't copulate efficiently their semens and ovaries can start a new life.

I can't give a counterexample of a species which was bred artificially by human for so long in a new direction that a new species (whose specimens by definition were not able to reproduce with the specimens of the base species) was created.

It's not that I am becoming creationist... but is there any exception from that rule for any artificially bred animal species?

[Edit]
This question has nothing to do with [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/52700/why-do-the-ancestors-of-birds-still-exist)
I am strictly asking about examples of an **artificially bred animal species** which got bred into two species.

[Edit 2]
Also to be exact, I am not interesed in specimens that can't reproduce due to various "external" circumstances like environment's temperature or size (chihuahuas&hound example). I am interested in specimens which come from the same base species and can't reproduce even with the help of in vitro fertilization (I know this is not exactly the definition of **species**). I just want to avoid getting answer similar to [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17799/have-we-ever-observed-two-drosophila-lineages-that-evolved-reproductive-isolatio).

Comment: Note that there are many definitions of "species", and you've chosen one that was specifically devised for evolutionary theory. In any case, rather than animals you might look into crops such as corn and its ancestor [teosinte](https://www.nsf.gov/news/news_summ.jsp?cntn_id=104207), the [Brassica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brassica) family, etc. It's pretty pointless, though, to try to reason someone out of a position they didn't reach by reason.

Comment: On top of the marked duplicate which seems very central to your misunderstanding, you might want to consider having a look at [Have we ever observed two drosophila lineages that evolved reproductive isolation in labs?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17799/have-we-ever-observed-two-drosophila-lineages-that-evolved-reproductive-isolatio). Of course, crops are also examples that come to mind (such as corn and teosinte for example).

Comment: @Remi.b,  I don't agree this is a duplicate of the ancestor-of-birds question that you marked up; this one asks about humans breeding organisms, not natural evolution. The drosophila question you mention in you comment does answer this question though.

Comment: That is exactly my point

Comment: @Roland. Ok, I've reopened the post. Thanks for feedback. The question might arguably be a duplicate of [Have we ever observed two drosophila lineages that evolved reproductive isolation in labs?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17799/have-we-ever-observed-two-drosophila-lineages-that-evolved-reproductive-isolatio) though but an answer based on some crop would probably be a better fit. Note that there is likely reproductive isolation between a chihuahua and a wolf despite taken as example of something of no interest in the question

Comment: You many want to tell your friend that saying evolution can happen but not to the point of new species is like saying you can walk around the block but its impossible to walk across the country. The mechanism is identical all that changes is how long the mechanisms runs.

Comment: This page contains a list of observed speciation events including a breakdown by mechanism and starts with a rather good introduction to the concept. http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/faq-speciation.html

Comment: Why - and I'm not saying your question is wrong - but why does it have to be a new species? Doesn't any significant mutation (e.g. the mutation allowing lactase to be expressed into adulthood) suffice? Does not the fossil record suffice? Your friend's arguement is based on the difference between selective breeding and the cumulative effect of many mutations. I don't think you finding a new species through selective breeding proves anything. imo.

Comment: @John I’d like to give you some advice in order to be more effective when talking to creationists.  As I pointed out in [this post](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/55984/a-better-definition-of-evolution) , creationists challenge evolutionists with what they call the bait-and-switch (see their link I posted).  AGAIN, creationists fully believe in adaptation via genetic variation and NS.  To them this is NOT evolution that will turn worms into women.  Your ‘walk around the block/across the country’ falls directly into that, and is completely ineffective against a creationists.

Comment: No offense Runz but I know all this, I also know that if what the believe is wrong you do them no service by pretending it is not. The mechanisms are identical are the same thing and pretending otherwise only helps them deny reality. It plays right into their false belief in "kinds" by acting as if there is some great diffrence between a change in a population and and change in population we happen to label as speciation.

Comment: @John, No offense as well, but do understand that there IS a difference between N.S. based on variation of existing genetic variety, and the CREATION of new phenotypes via genetic material that did not exist before.  Creationists are well aware of this difference.  You need to be as well.

Comment: Yes there is a difference new genetic material and existing.  However new genetic material is NOT speciation and new genetic material  is actually quite common in the "population level" evolution they accept. furthermore new material is not necessary for speciation. Again both "types" of evolution are the same mechanism both may or may not have new genetic material but do have a selective process. They are trying to create an distinction where there is not one and using ambiguous terminology to make it seem as if they are not. If you want to continue this in discussion feel free.

Answer (score 3):

There are indeed many examples of new species created by humans, and observed to arise by humans. Many via deliberate experimentation. You can find examples googling "examples of speciation", looking at the Wikipedia page for speciation or the Talk Origins one:

http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/faq-speciation.html

http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/speciation.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speciation

The issue is that there are two events of interest in "the origin of species" that are related but not the same thing: there is speciation, and then there is overall change. And as far as change itself goes you can have genetic change and phenotypic change which themselves aren't perfectly correlated.

Speciation is a very important evolutionary event, as it's the point at which genetic material is no longer exchanged between two groups and so they start evolving independently, meaning differences will accumulate over time (steadily and inevitably for genetic differences, more variably for phenotypic ones as that depends on the environment). But you can have differences accumulating without speciation (especially not with your "in vitro fertilization" criterion, which allows gene flow to be stopped for a long time without "speciation" by that definition happening), and you can have speciation happen without much genetic or phenotypic change.

And so on our human timescale we'll tend to see three categories of events:

1) large phenotypic change without speciation (especially by the in-vitro definition), because natural selection can cause large phenotypic change but random mutation cannot be rushed and that genetic drift is usually what will make groups no longer inter-fertile,

2) Speciation without large phenotypic change, again because speciation is just the beginning and all you need for "speciation" is just enough change to make interbreeding impossible or difficult, and so many examples of observed speciation involve just that, and

3) Speciation with large phenotypic change, which will usually be single-generation events with hybridization and polyploidy. Those are the most likely to fit your criteria that in-vitro fertilization shouldn't work. And they **are** legitimate and important evolutionary processes; polyploidy has happened many times in our lineage, it's an important source of genetic diversity, and hybridization and polyploidy are a major mechanism in the evolution of plants in particular. But they're not the major mechanism for the evolution of large vertebrates, so it's easy for Creationists to dismiss them.

Still, looking at the links I gave you I see a few examples that involve genetic change sufficient to block even in-vitro fertilization. The second Talk Origins link in particular refers to examples where speciation was determined by the offspring being sterile. There is also an article in the notes of the Wikipedia page about a recent discovery about the kind of genetic changes that can lead to speciation:

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/wandering-fly-gene-suppor/

The general problem with giving Creationists examples though, is that the examples they want don't exist (and would usually contradict the theory of evolution anyway) and the ones that do exist they're not satisfied by (because the change involved isn't dramatic enough, or IS dramatic but as a result makes the dramatic look trivial because it happened via a small gradual underlying change - which, you know, is how evolution is thought to work).

I notice in fact that **you** are the one asking about the speciation with in-vitro fertilization, not your friend; your friend apparently just said that huskies and chihuahuas are not comparable to fish vs tetrapods. If this is personal curiosity from you then that's fine; if you are looking for arguments for your friend specifically then it looks like you're on the wrong track, since no amount of lack-of-interbreeding will make flies any less flies, which is usually the issue for people who focus on "fish to tetrapod" as a scale of change.

You might have better luck figuring out exactly what claims your friend makes, where they set the boundaries of what they think is possible and what they think it isn't, and then find an example that breaks that specific boundary. So they say "speciation can't happen !", you reply "speciation happened in fruit flies", and they answer "so what, fish haven't become tetrapods" - but, what is it they *meant* by "speciation can't happen" ? What mechanism do they think makes it impossible, what do they think this "speciation" is that's impossible, where do they set the boundary for themselves between "ordinary change that can happen" and "stuff that can't happen so evolution is false" ? They probably don't know clearly themselves, but figuring it out and addressing it is a better way of moving forward, and you both can learn things. And it makes it a bit easier for you too - you don't have to worry about finding proof that fish can become tetrapods, you can be like "OK fish can't become tetrapods whatever, but you said that new species cannot arise through genetic change, but here is a paper saying that a gene transposition makes it impossible for those two flies to interbreed, wouldn't that be an example of speciation via genetic change ? What do you think ?"